# What to think about before defining function as Object.prototype extension or just function?

Tags: javascript, performance, function, prototype

For example I have to add 'foo' to string.

So I have at least two ways to go.

First, I can implement String.prototype.foo:

```
String.prototype.foo = function() {
    return this + 'foo';
};

var s = 'str';
var data = s.foo(); // "strfoo"
```

Another way:

```
function foo(str) {
    return str + 'foo';
}

var s = 'str';
var data = foo(s); // "strfoo"
```

Both look pretty. But should I think about any "underwater rocks" before choosing first or second implementation? Are there any significant reasons, such as efficiency and performance?

Comment: In first example, you are using `this` context but in later example, you are using argument.. Both practices are fine as long as you know what you are doing..

Answer (score 1):

The first **extend the functionalities of String**. 
Use this solution if you have a class of objects and you like to add new behaviours to it.

The second is more **an utility function**. 
Note also that you can apply the second foo also to a variable that is not a String, so you should also test the type of the argument if you like to limit the use to a String argument.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the globals in JavaScript is always a bad decision. Don't do that, except if it's not about making a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill).

The implications are multiple from your code being not portable to probability of breaking someone else's code.

I would always use the second method. Or if things are really that complicated maybe implement my own class of String.

```
function MyString(str) {
    this.str = str;
}

MyString.prototype.foo = function() { return this.str + "foo" };

var s = new MyString("str");

var data = s.foo(); // "strfoo"
```

Here is further reading about modifying global objects and the downsides :

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea